# Launch lync-2013 app from wp 8 app (and pass parameters to it)

Tags: windows-phone-8, lync-2013

I am trying to launch a Lync-2013 app from the Windows Phone 8 app that I am developing.

I will be passing the number that lync client will call.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the lync: protocol to activate the app:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("lync:<sip:user1@hotmail.com>"));
```

Comment: Thanks Josue I was able to launch the Lync app. but how can I pass extra parameters like suppose if some one has already logged in lync so directly he can make a call . Can u please give  me some any references where I can look for all the possible scenarios. Thanks man

Comment: Hi Danish! I can't test this as my office365 account doesn't want to work with Lync for Windows Phone, but here you have a lot of info about launching lync: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398376.aspx

Comment: Well Josue i have already visited that Lync. Can u tell me that how we check that Lync is installed or not in wp8

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You only launch the Uri, if no app is installed who can handle it, the phone ask to search in the store. But you can't detect if another app is installed already in the system.